# Matlab plot Latex style

Tags: siunitx, matlab

I would like to have the units on the axis from a Matlab plot with the correct form like SIunitx in LATEX. 
Is this possible?

This is the line that I would like to have different: **no u, but μ**.

```
xlabel('C [uF]', 'fontsize', 20,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Comment: Well seems like you cannot add additional LaTeX packages in Matlab (https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/368641-add-more-latex-packages-for-latex-interpreter-in-matlab#comment_507908). Exactly how should it be different? I.e., what does it look like now, and how do you want it to look?

Comment: I would like to have micro sign instead of u for example.

Comment: Hard to guess when there was no mu in your example. But Matlab understands some TeX syntax (see the dokumentation), so I think you can just write `\mu` to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need matlab2tikz: https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz

This is a plug-in using tikz, output tikz code from matlab, and modify symbols from the code, with latex compilation

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Just write `\mu` in your `xlabel`. Matlab can understand some TeX syntax, see https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#f68-481090_sep_shared-Interpreter (though this does not mean it actually uses TeX).

---

Addition: as you will see from the Matlab documentation, you can make Matlab use LaTeX to typeset text, with the `'Interpreter', 'LaTeX'` option. I've never really used this feature much, and don't really know any details about it. It appears that in earlier versions of Matlab it was possible to add packages to the preamble used, but that changed around 2016 (https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/368641-add-more-latex-packages-for-latex-interpreter-in-matlab#comment_507908). Hence it's not possible to use e.g. `siunitx` in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

After endless searching on the internet, I didn't find a nice-looking answer, either. Nobody wants a math-italic-*µ*, followed by a "m" after some space, so it looks like *µ* m. Then, I asked myself "Why don't you try ASCII characters?" I looked up "µ" on the internet, copied it, pasted it into the plot label/title/etc. of Matlab and was done. It works and looks fine. No awkward font, just the usual one. Should work with all Greek letters.

Comment: I too disklike the wrongly italicized *µ* for units, but your solution does not work for me: MATLAB (2022b) converts straight Unicode µ into *µ* if the figure output is vectorized (with `exportgraphics(..., contenttype='vector')`). (I reported this bug to MATLAB and there is no workaround except for using the rasterized, `contenttype='image'` option, which correctly keeps the non-italic "µ".)