# correct way of writing the units on a graph

Tags: siunitx, matlab, units

What font should I use in Matlab for having the same one like in `LATEX`?

What is the right way to have the units on a graph?

1. use () or [] for unit of measurement? a or b?

   a.   `xlabel('$C (fF)$', 'fontsize', 20,'Interpreter','latex')`

   b.   `ylabel('Gm crit [uS]', 'fontsize', 20 ,'Interpreter','latex')`

Comment: Hm, that seems to be a pure Matlab question for me ... Have you asked the support of Matlab or on an mailing list or webpage handling Matlab issues?

Comment: I would like to know how can I use SIunitx in Matlab.

Comment: Hm, is that not a duplicate of your first question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505571/matlab-plot-latex-style ?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably checkout the [pgfplots](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package, it allows plotting using math functions or external data tables inside latex code. In my opinion, the result is way better than creating the plots in Matlab and then importing them to your file. Of course, it is compatible with the `siunitx` package and is consistent with font type and size.